# Receiving endless errors with the insert - statement

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am trying to insert some values into customer and then i get the ora-00904 error.
After i research about this problem, instead of using '' i used "". But now im receiving the ora-00984.

```
INSERT INTO customer (c_id, name, age)
VALUES (1, 'Carl', 45)
OUTPUT:
SQL-ERROR: ORA-00904: "name": invalid ID
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

then i tried this way.

```
INSERT INTO customer (c_id, name, age)
VALUES (1, "Carl", 45)
OUTPUT:
00984. 00000 -  "column not allowed here"
```

My DDL - Code:

```
CREATE TABLE adress (
adress_id   INTEGER NOT NULL,
state       VARCHAR2(60) NOT NULL,
country     VARCHAR2(60) NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE adress ADD CONSTRAINT adress_pk PRIMARY KEY ( adress_id );
CREATE TABLE contract (
con_id   INTEGER NOT NULL,
length   DATE
);
ALTER TABLE contract ADD CONSTRAINT contract_pk PRIMARY KEY ( con_id );
CREATE TABLE customer (
c_id               INTEGER NOT NULL,
name               VARCHAR2(60) NOT NULL,
age                CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
adress_adress_id   INTEGER
);
ALTER TABLE customer ADD CONSTRAINT customer_pk PRIMARY KEY ( c_id );
CREATE TABLE relation_1 (
customer_c_id     INTEGER NOT NULL,
contract_con_id   INTEGER NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE relation_1 ADD CONSTRAINT relation_1_pk PRIMARY KEY ( customer_c_id,
                                                              contract_con_id);
ALTER TABLE customer
ADD CONSTRAINT customer_adress_fk FOREIGN KEY ( adress_adress_id )
    REFERENCES adress ( adress_id );
ALTER TABLE relation_1
ADD CONSTRAINT relation_1_contract_fk FOREIGN KEY ( contract_con_id )
    REFERENCES contract ( con_id );
ALTER TABLE relation_1
ADD CONSTRAINT relation_1_customer_fk FOREIGN KEY ( customer_c_id )
    REFERENCES customer ( c_id );
```

Comment: This is not valid SQL syntax, you should replace the second `INTO` with `VALUES`.

Comment: Sorry for that, i corrected it . ofcourse i used values and not into

Comment: c_id is the primary key which autoincrements and cant be inserted?

Comment: i have edited my ddl - Code

Comment: The posted DDL builds successfully, and, given that, the first INSERT statement succeeds. So is there a real question here?

Comment: it works? when i trying to use this insert statement it does not work ora 00904 appears

Answer (score 1):

The syntax uses `VALUES()` for the list of values:

```
INSERT INTO customer (c_id, name, age)
    VALUES (1, 'Carl', 45);
```

You can also use a `SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO customer (c_id, name, age)
    SELECT 1, 'Carl', 45
    FROM dual;
```

Note that in both cases, the delimiter for the string is *single quotes* not *double quotes*.

Comment: Excuse me for my misspelling, i used values instead of into

Answer (score 0):

In SQL we use single quotes for string literals. Double quotes are used (optionally) for identifiers such as table and column names. You have used double quotes around the value of `carl` and that's why Oracle hurls ORA-00984.

Why you got ORA-00904 for the first statement is a mystery. Probably there is something awry with your definition of `customer` but unless you post the table structure we cannot be sure.

Comment: Thanks now i know that "" is that a way on inserting values. I edited my structure